# IBM RFT JTree - Click Subitem without knowing text

Tags: jtree, rft

I have a JTree in my Java application which changes the labels of subitems with configuration of language. Because of this, I need to click the subitems by index or any other way.

For example, I need the call JTree.click(atPath("test1->test2")) without knowing the strings. I tried this with calling JTree.click(atIndex(1)), this works for clicking "test1", one of the firtst subitems. Afterwards some new subitems pop up below "test1". But I cant click them by using atIndex(), RFT doesnt click anything if I try to click any index again.
Now the only way I see is to click by absolut screen position, but this isnt really the way I m looking for.

Maybe anybody of you had the same problem or has any idea. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, its possible to use more than one Index. For example:

```
jtree.click(atList(atIndex(0), atIndex(3)));
```